# List all Mercurial repositories cloned under a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, mercurial, batch-processing

I have a `C:\Dev` folder, where I have cloned multiple Mercurial repositories. How do I get a list of those, so I can then clone them on a different PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to write a batch script to do that and then use the `hg paths default` in each directory.

Put the something along those line in a new .bat file and then run it in your `C:\Dev` directory :

```
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO hg -r %%G paths default
```

It is been a long time since I didn't wrote a batch file and I don't have a Windows machine to test it on, so it may need some modifications in order to work.

Good luck !